Gauss hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(\lambda,\lambda;2\lambda\mid z)$
I just answered this question, in which the Gauss hypergeometric function appears as part of the solution. Specifically, the solutions were of the form
$$f(\lambda ;z)={}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda~,~\lambda \\ 2\lambda\end{matrix}\bigg|~z\right)$$
I am curious if $f(\lambda; z)$ has any simpler expressions. I was able to find this formula on functions.wolfram.com which allows one to write
$${}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda~,~\lambda \\ 2\lambda\end{matrix}\bigg|~z\right)=2^{2\lambda-1}\Gamma\left(\lambda+\frac{1}{2}\right)z^{1/2-\lambda}(1-z)^{-1/4}~P^{1/2-\lambda}_{-1/2}\left(\frac{2-z}{2\sqrt{1-z}}\right) \\ \text{for}~~\Re\left(\frac{2-z}{2\sqrt{1-z}}\right)>0$$
However, the $P^\mu_\nu(\cdot)$ is an associated Legendre function, which, unfortunately, for non-integer parameters may only be defined via the hypergeometric function, and hence we end up with a circular argument.
There is of course the integral formula, which in this case may be written as
$${}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda~,~\lambda \\ 2\lambda\end{matrix}\bigg|~z\right)=\frac{{\Gamma(\lambda)}^2}{\Gamma(2\lambda)}\int_0^1 t^{\lambda-1}(1-t)^{\lambda-1}(1-zt)^{-\lambda}~\mathrm dt \\ \text{for}~~\Re \lambda > 0$$
However, I don't know if this is tractable.
Wolfram Alpha is able to evaluate a few special values, in particular when $\lambda$ is an integer, for example it finds
$${}_2F_1(1,1;2\mid x)=\frac{-\log(1-x)}{x}$$
But it fails to simplify ${}_2F_1(0.5;0.5,1\mid x)$.
Thanks for any insights!

There is problrm to generate the $$f(\lambda ,z)={}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda~,~\lambda \\ 2\lambda\end{matrix}\bigg|~z\right)$$ when $\lambda$ is a positive integer.
If $\lambda$ is half a positive integer, the result is given in terms of elliptic integrals
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2},z\right)=\frac{2 K(z)}{\pi }$$
$$f\left(\frac{3}{2},z\right)=-\frac{16 (z-2) K(z)}{\pi 
   z^2}-\frac{32 E(z)}{\pi  z^2}$$
$$f\left(\frac{5}{2},z\right)=\frac{256 \left(3 z^2-16 z+16\right)
   K(z)}{9 \pi  z^4}+\frac{2048 (z-2)E(z)}{9 \pi  z^4}$$
$$f\left(\frac{7}{2},z\right)=-\frac{2048 \left(15 z^3-158 z^2+384
   z-256\right) K(z)}{75 \pi z^6}-$$ $$\frac{4096 \left(23 z^2-128
   z+128\right) E(z)}{75 \pi  z^6}$$

Neat result! How did you find these?
